# AWS Aurora common table expressions (CTE's)

Tags: amazon-aurora

Is it possible to write CTE's in AWS aurora? i.e. is there `WITH` support?

If not, how do you achieve the same thing in aurora?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Aurora currently mimics MySQL 5.6 which does not support it. It's less flexible with backends but supports the same SQL: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Overview.html

Aurora is planned to mimic PostgreSQL which supports modern SQL, so that will be an option in the future: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/faqs/